# It is possible to manage the focus on the react-native-video player?

Tags: react-native

We are planning to use the [react-native-video player](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video) on our app and we would like to show/hide the controls on focus, specifically:

- On gaining focus - video player controls are displayed
- On losing focus - video player controls are hidden

Do you guys know if this is possible, or how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

I read the `react-native-video` API, give you the following solution

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state={
     isShowControl:false
  }

}
....
<Video
        ...
 disableFocus={this.state.isShowControl} // disables audio focus and wake lock (default false)
onAudioFocusChanged={this.onAudioFocusChanged} // Callback when audio focus has been lost - pause if focus has been lost
      />
```

...

```
onAudioFocusChanged = (event: { hasAudioFocus: boolean }) => {
    if(event.hasAudioFocus) {
      this.setState({ isShowControl: false })
    } else {
       this.setState({ isShowControl: true })      
    }
```

if you want more control about the video component, you can use `react-native-video-controls`